# Center Tapped Full Wave Rectifier

Tags: rectifier

What is the formula for V<sub>dc</sub> of a Center tapped full wave rectifier?

Is it

`0.636*Vac - Vk` (where V<sub>k</sub> is the potential drop across a single diode. Assume both diodes have the same cutoff voltage)

or is it

`0.636*Vac - 2Vk`

It's not given anywhere in my textbook and I couldn't find it on the internet either. Logically the first one makes more sense to me because for every half-cycle, input voltage is across just one diode unlike in a full wave bridge rectifier where the input voltage is across two diodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2*Vsecondary/Pi - Vk` or as you put it `0.636*Vac - Vk`.